# How to execute a TestNG test case outside a project, using Maven Multi module

Tags: java, maven, testing, testng, multi-module

I am working on a multi module maven project.

My Project Structure is as below - 
**Parent-Module** (Packaging - pom)
**BaseFramework** (Packaging - jar)
**TestProject**  (Packaging - jar) (Added BaseFramework as a dependency in pom.xml of the project)
**TestRunner** (Packaging - jar) (Added BaseFramework and TestProject as a dependency in pom.xml of the project)

**TestProject** has a **testNG.xml file** which executes the test cases of the specified class.
Test cases uses Data providers and path is mentioned as relative path (**./src/main/resources/pmRolDetailsWithId.xml)**

**TestRunner** project has a Suite Runner file (lets say SuiteRunner.xml) Which contains the path of testNG.xml from (TestProject).

When executed, the test tries to find the "pmRolDetailsWithId.xml" file in TestRunner Project.
Path - **/TestRunner**/src/main/resources/pmRolDetailsWithId.xml and the file is not found.

Expected it should fetch the file from **TestProject** .
i.e. the path should be **/TestProject**/src/main/resources/pmRolDetailsWithId.xml

I think the root project is not getting changed when the test control goes form TestRunner Project - TestProject

Please correct me If I am missing something and help me to resolve this issue.

Attaching screenshot of the error.

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrdwT.png)

Comment: please add relavent message in the picture to the post.

Comment: Added the image description.

Comment: Please replace the screenshot by the actual text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

I had to change the way I was giving the relative path of the file.

**Earlier -** 
Filepath - /src/main/resoruces/pmRolDetailsWithId.xml

and since execution was triggered from a different module, the complete path was
 
/users/xyz/Parent-Module/TestRunner/src/main/resoruces/pmRolDetailsWithId.xml

**Changed -** 
Filepath - **../TestProject**/src/main/resoruces/pmRolDetailsWithId.xml

And now the complete path was 
/users/xyz/Parent-Module/TestRunner/../TestProject/src/main/resoruces/pmRolDetailsWithId.xml